# How do I vectorize a for loop in python that utilises state variables i.e. a for loop that checks current state during calculation

Tags: python, for-loop, vectorization

How do I vectorize the following for loop that has memory of its current state (the variable 'current_state' below)? I've trivialized the function here, the real one is a bit more complex but the structure is the same - it's just running on too big an array to be time effective. In summary: I need to know when and how many times a signal, stored in 'test_array' crosses above or below a certain threshold:

```
test_array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
results_array = []

current_state = '<=3'

for i in range(len(test_array)):
    if current_state == 'mid' and test_array[i] >= 7:
        current_state = '>=7'
        results_array.append((i,current_state))

    if current_state == 'mid' and test_array[i] <= 3:
        current_state = '<=3'
        results_array.append((i,current_state))

    if current_state == '>=7' and test_array[i] < 7:
        current_state = 'mid'
        results_array.append((i,current_state))            

    if current_state == '<=3' and test_array[i] > 3:
        current_state = 'mid'
        results_array.append((i,current_state))

print results_array
```

I've searched stackoverflow for 2 days now but can't find a similar example that utilises a state variable like this. If I'm just looking in the wrong place please accept my apologies and point me to the right place. Thank you again kind codelords!

Comment: Vectorize what? If the processing of elements depends on earlier values, then you can't process them in parallel (if that's what you mean).

Comment: Yes that is what I mean i.e. to process elements depending on earlier values, and thanks for your response. Is it safe to assume then that what I'm asking is impossible given the serial nature of the data analysis?

Comment: Yes, that's a safe assumption.Some processes are simply serial by their nature. "Parallelizing" something requires find and executing independent portions of what needs to be done.

Comment: Understood - thanks for clearing that up for me!!

Comment: If the state variable potentially holds information about the full input history, then indeed you cannot vectorize the processing, I agree. However, your example may be a special case because it's not clear to me whether your input can jump from states `<3` to `>7` (or vice versa) and you intentionally ignore this case in your loop to add inertia, which actually makes the state variable necessary. Otherwise, the current state would merely represent the previous sample so you could definitely discard the state variable and vectorize this processing using a 2-samples window.